# grep information through multiple line

Tags: regex, grep

I have this information:

```
not what i want
ul
text1
text1
/ul
not what i want
not what i want
ul
texttext2
texttext2
texttext2
/ul
not what i want
```

How to get data between 'ul' and '/ul'?

I have tried `grep -oP 'ul.*?/ul'`

My desired output is:

```
ul
text1
text1
/ul
ul
texttext2
texttext2
texttext2
/ul
```

Comment: Thanks to add expected output.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks ,i added .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
awk '/ul/,/\/ul/' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/ul/,/\/ul/p' file
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print if /ul/ .. /\/ul/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` and PCRE with some help from `tr` and bash process substitution:

```
$ grep -oP ul.*?ul <(cat file | tr '\n' _) | tr _ '\n'
ul
text1
text1
/ul
ul
texttext2
texttext2
texttext2
/ul
```

- `<(cat file | tr '\n' _)` replace newlines with underscores
- `grep -oP ul.*?ul` get `ul—/ul` ranges
- `tr _ '\n'` replace underscores back to newlines

Comment: I prefer when you sing than when you spawn so much `forks()` ^^

Comment: You already took all good answers ;D besides _Oh yes I got-to (make it funky)_

Comment: voted up just for the fun time and the respect I have for the most electric (even dead) guy in the world (apart Jimmy Hendrix ... who is dead too)